# Chunk and pipe big amounts of data for client-site (browser) PDF generation

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, stream, pipe

I'm trying to download HTML/JSON data from a webserver (Node.js) and convert it to PDF on the client-side. I wish to do the processing on the user's browser so my server don't get overloaded with pdfs conversions.

It shouldn't be a problem if the data wasn't so big. A report (the data downloaded from the server) can sum 200, 300MB and the browsers can't handle so much data in memory. Because of that, I (probably) need to download and save the data in chunks, or pipe it directly to the PDF converter.

But I can't get my head around it. How can I slice & store/pipe the downloaded data? I've been looking around and found several libraries, but I still didn't get how to make them work together. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the required size of data that should be sent to browser ?

Comment: It goes from 50Kb to 800MB, 900MB.

Comment: couldn't you use chunked-responses or websockets for chunk-wise data transfer to the client? the piecewise pdf generation on the client still is challenging though.

Comment: yes, @lipp, that's precisely the problem... how to generate the pdf without having it stored in memory.

Comment: Have you checked out [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), it is a client-side pdf generator, and I would not be surpirsed if they have a solution to an issue like this, and perhaps you can use that for inspiration.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/index.html)

Comment: See http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @guest271314, it's the other way around, actually: I need to convert html to pdf.

Comment: @AFMeirelles Requirement is to download `html` to client-side ? If `html` or `json` is data , can request `kb` per request, reassemble when all requests complete ? See https://www.openoffice.org/

Comment: Yes, @cojomojo, I've tried out jsPDF and the first test converting html to PDF wasn't successful... ok, I haven't tried hard enough. It would be nice if I had a library that can add page breaks "automatically", but I guess I'll have to write down code to do that. BTW, I'll have a look at msgpack, thanks!

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it could be done downloading and saving the data in chunks, but sooner or later I'd have to reassemble it... and it is done in memory, which leads to out of memory problems in the browser. That is, if no streaming is possible, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's a good idea to have app consumers generating 800MB pdf files on their computers.

I would avoid JSON in the case of large records.  If there is over 25 MB of actual records data, I would send that data in binary/compressed form.

As for viewing all this data, I don't even think PDF is the way to go.  I would create a special offline viewer for the end consumer. Perhaps a custom browser plugin or extension so that they don't have to throw 800MB in memory when they're viewing a report.

Another consideration might be to use Google Drive or Rackspace OpenCloud or AWS or something of that nature, reason being, if something goes wrong on the consumer's end halfway through the transfer, your server will have to start all over too. If you throw it in the cloud behind a CDN, then they can download it however many times they need to, from a server that's close to them.  Also your server should be able to send it to the cloud much faster than sending it to the client so less time that your server has resources tied open.

Comment: Interesting point of view. Can you tell me more why do you think it's a bad idea to generate the pdf on the client-side? I was thinking it would be better to push the processing cost to the user, so my server don't get flooded by several processing requests - and I don't need a bigger server. It lowers the overall cost of the application. As for the PDF being the best format or not, unfortunately it's not an option, it's a business requirement.

Comment: I agree that delegating as much work to clients as possible is best.  I have a feeling I would strongly fight that requirement though because I tend to doubt it would be the best experience for the end consumer.  But in order to determine an optimal solution, I would need to know exactly what the raw data is and exactly what information the consumer is supposed to obtain from the raw data.  For example, I built a windfarm management system.  Raw data is blade damage/repair details.  Customer gets PDF reports with charts and details, but the reports are scoped to one project inspection/repair.